# Add directory structure in (frontend)module

Tags: module, magento-1

I'm creating a module. This all works fine. Put the thing is that I can access my module using: "/userproducts". But I don't know how to add a 'directory' structure so that I can use: "/userproducts" *and* "/userproducts/ajax"?

That I can have (besides the `public function indexAction()` ) something like: `public function ajaxAction()`

config:

```
<config>
    <global>
        <modules>
                <TEST_Userprods>
                        <version>0.1.0</version>
                </TEST_Userprods>
        </modules>
    <blocks>
        <userprods>
            <rewrite><userprods>TEST_Userprods_Block_Userprods</userprods></rewrite>
        </userprods>
    </blocks>
    </global>
        <frontend>
            <routers>
                <userprods>
                    <use>standard</use>
                    <args>
                          <module>TEST_Userprods</module>
                          <frontName>userproducts</frontName>
                    </args>
                </userprods>
            </routers>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <userprods>
                      <file>userprods.xml</file>
                </userprods>
            </updates>
        </layout>
        <translate>
            <modules>
                <translations>
                    <files>
                        <default>TEST_Userprods.csv</default>
                    </files>
                </translations>
            </modules>
        </translate>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

Indexcontroller:

```
class TEST_Userprods_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
     $this->loadLayout(array('default'));
     $this->renderLayout();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to be able to access `/userproducts/ajax` you need an `AjaxController.php` similar to `IndexController.php` and an `indexAction()` inside it.
The default url structure is `module/controller/action`.
If one of the parts is missing it defaults to 'index'.
So `/userproducts` is similar to `userproducts/index/index`.
`/userproducts/ajax` is similar to `userproducts/ajax/index`.
If you want to put the `ajaxAction` inside the `IndexController` you should call it in the browser like this: `userproducts/index/ajax`.

Comment: Aha, I got it! Awesome, thanks! I'm starting to understand when the config is needed and when the structure vs. class-structure is enough.